# Display each array in a 2D array with tabulate vertically

Tags: python, tabulate

Currently, my python script tabulates this 2D array:
`[['Aquania', 'Castle Of Time', 'Colour Circuit', 'Comet Starway'], ['Crystal Dungeon', 'Ds Bowser Castle', 'Desert Fort', 'Dragon Burial Grounds'], ['Dreamworld Cloudway', 'Forest Creek', 'Gba Bowser Castle 2', 'Heart Of China'], ['Infernal Pipeyard', 'Jiyuu Village', 'Lunar Lights', 'Mushroom Valley'], ['Sahara Hideout', 'White Garden', 'White Garden', 'White Garden']]`
And it outputs it like this:

```
Cup 1                Cup 2             Cup 3                Cup 4
-------------------  ----------------  -------------------  ---------------------
Aquania              Castle Of Time    Colour Circuit       Comet Starway
Crystal Dungeon      Ds Bowser Castle  Desert Fort          Dragon Burial Grounds
Dreamworld Cloudway  Forest Creek      Gba Bowser Castle 2  Heart Of China
Infernal Pipeyard    Jiyuu Village     Lunar Lights         Mushroom Valley
Sahara Hideout       White Garden      White Garden         White Garden
```

However, I would like it to print with the first array in the 2d array going vertically so:

```
Cup 1
-------------------
Aquania
Castle Of Time
Colour Circuit
Comet Starway
```

and so on for all the other columns
Is there a way to do this with tabulate?

Answer (score 0):

Is this something that you're after?

```
import pandas as pd
def transpose_list_of_lists(list_of_lists):
    """
    This function converts a list of lists to a dataframe.

    :param list_of_lists: The list of lists to convert.
    :return: The dataframe.
    """
    return pd.DataFrame(list_of_lists).transpose()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about tabulate but you could use pandas to do something like this.

```py
import pandas as pd

data =[
    ["Aquania", "Castle Of Time", "Colour Circuit", "Comet Starway"],
    ["Crystal Dungeon", "Ds Bowser Castle", "Desert Fort", "Dragon Burial Grounds"],
    ["Dreamworld Cloudway", "Forest Creek", "Gba Bowser Castle 2", "Heart Of China"],
    ["Infernal Pipeyard", "Jiyuu Village", "Lunar Lights", "Mushroom Valley"],
    ["Sahara Hideout", "White Garden", "White Garden", "White Garden"],
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.index = [f'Cup{idx+1}' for idx in range(0, len(df))]

print(df.T)

             Cup1                   Cup2                 Cup3               Cup4            Cup5
0         Aquania        Crystal Dungeon  Dreamworld Cloudway  Infernal Pipeyard  Sahara Hideout
1  Castle Of Time       Ds Bowser Castle         Forest Creek      Jiyuu Village    White Garden
2  Colour Circuit            Desert Fort  Gba Bowser Castle 2       Lunar Lights    White Garden
3   Comet Starway  Dragon Burial Grounds       Heart Of China    Mushroom Valley    White Garden
```

Comment: This looks good, would the numbers going down still be there? If so is it possible to remove them?